# How to override default namespace when refering to another document

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have two input documents called foo.xml and bar.xml defined like this

foo.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<foo:IMM-contents xmlns:foo="http://whatever"
                  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<class name="MyClassName"/>
</foo:IMM-contents>
```

bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<bar/>
```

and my XSLT (using XSL 2.0) named foobar.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:foo="http://whatever"
                xpath-default-namespace="urn:something:*"
            >
  <xsl:output method="text"
              encoding="utf8"
              />

  <xsl:param name="fooFile" select="'foo.xml'"/>

  <xsl:variable name="fooDoc" select="document($fooFile)"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="$fooDoc/foo:IMM-contents/class">
      <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If I now run the XSLT this happens

```
$ java -jar saxon9he.jar bar.xml -xsl:foobar.xsl
$
```

That is "nothing".

But if I remove the line

```
xpath-default-namespace="urn:something:*"
```

from the XSLT and re-run I get this

```
$ java -jar saxon9he.jar bar.xml -xsl:foobar.xsl
MyClassName$
```

**My question is simply**, how can I retain the line

```
xpath-default-namespace="urn:something:*"
```

in my XSLT and still get the output "MyClassName" without modifying files foo.xml and bar.xml?

Comment: Why are you complicating the question with non-essentials? The bar.xml document is completely irrelevant to the problem. You could (and should) have presented an example where foo.xml is the input document.

Comment: I made a small mistake when constructing the bar.xml file. It should look like this

Comment: Editing mistake. :(

It should read

I made a small mistake when constructing the bar.xml file. It should look like this

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<bar xmlns="urn:something:*">
<attribute>attr1</attribute>
<attribute>attr2</attribute>
</bar>`

Comment: and foo.xml should contain some additional data like this

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<foo:IMM-contents xmlns:foo="http://whatever"
                  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<class name="MyClassName">
  <rdn>
    <name>attr1</name>
  </rdn>
</class>
<class name="AnotherClass">
  <rdn>
    <name>attr2</name>
  </rdn>
</class>
</foo:IMM-contents>`

and the XSLT should now use the attributes found in in bar.xml to print the class-names containing the corresponding attributes using foo.xml.

Answer (score 1):

You could change:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$fooDoc/foo:IMM-contents/class">
```

to:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$fooDoc/foo:IMM-contents/*:class">
```

That will select `class` in *any* namespace. A more proper solution would narrow the selection down to `class` in no-namespace only:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$fooDoc/foo:IMM-contents/*:class[not(namespace-uri())]">
```

Comment: Thank you. Both proposed solutions seems to give the correct answer to my question. Did not think of that you could use `*` for the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

A few options for how to adjust your XPath to match the **class** element:

1. `$fooDoc/foo:IMM-contents/*:class`
2. `$fooDoc/foo:IMM-contents/*:class[namespace-uri()='']`
3. `$fooDoc/foo:IMM-contents/*:class[not(namespace-uri())]`
4. `$fooDoc/foo:IMM-contents/*[local-name()='class']`
5. `$fooDoc/foo:IMM-contents/*[local-name()='class' and namespace-uri()='']`

Comment: Thank you. Both proposed solutions seems to give the correct answer to my question. Did not think of that you could use `*` for the namespace.

Comment: * to match any namespace(including no namespace) was added in 2.0